# Plot a graph of the effect of distance of separation between the TX/RX and the receive signal strength

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot a graph of the effect of distance of separation between the TX/RX and the received signal strength using Friis's free space equation.

I am having an issue with the graph. When my pr is in dbm unit, the value is not correct.

My code is below:

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

d = 1:0.1:20 ;
f = 2100000000;
Wavelength = (3*10^8/f).^2;
PT = 50.12;
PR = (Wavelength./(4*pi*d).^2)*PT ;
PR1 = 10*log(PR/(10*10.^-3)) ;

subplot(2,1,1);
plot(d,PR);
xlabel('x--> D (distance in Km)');
ylabel('y--> PR (Received power in Watts)');
title('Distance of separation between the TX/RX and the receive signal strength');
grid on

subplot(2,1,2);
plot(d,PR1);
xlabel('x--> D (distance in Meter)');
ylabel('y--> PR (Received power in dBm)');
title('Distance of separation between the TX/RX and the receive signal strength');
grid on;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert for what concerns the subject of your computations, but it seems that your second subplot contains two errors: a scale error (the X-axis should use meters as basic unit instead of kilometers) and a conversion error (the shift from watts to dBm should be calculated differently).

The first problem is very easy to fix. In order to obtain the distance in meters, starting from kilometers, just do this:

```
d1 = d .* 1000;
```

Now, for what concerns the second problem, I think you should proceed as follows:

```
dBW = 10 * log10(PR)

dBm = 10 * log10(1000 * PR)
    = 10 * log10(PR) + 10 * log10(1000)
    = 10 * log10(PR) + 10 * 3
    = 10 * log10(PR) + 30
    = dBW + 30
```

Thus:

```
PR1 = (10 .* log10(PR)) + 30;
```

Here is the final code:

```
clc();
close all;
clear all;

f = 2100000000;
wl = ((3 * 10^8) / f) ^ 2;
PT = 50.12;

d = 1:0.1:20;
PR = (wl ./ ((4 .* pi() .* d) .^ 2)) .* PT;

d1 = d .* 1000;
PR1 = (10 .* log10(PR)) + 30;

subplot(2,1,1);
plot(d,PR);
xlabel('x --> D (Distance in Km)');
ylabel('y --> PR (Received Power in Watts)');
title('Distance of separation between the TX/RX and the receive signal strength');
grid on;

subplot(2,1,2);
plot(d1,PR1);
xlabel('x --> D (Distance in Meter)');
ylabel('y --> PR (Received Power in dBm)');
title('Distance of separation between the TX/RX and the receive signal strength');
grid on;
```

Comment: I just have one more question to ask my PT=47dbm and i converted it to  50.12 Watts,how can i do the conversion on matlab from dbm to watts?

Comment: Following the above formulation, it will be `W = 10 ^ ((dBm - 30) / 10)`.